# Google maps Places API not working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-places-api

```
package com.example.googlemapstestproject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnMapLongClickListener, OnMyLocationButtonClickListener,
        android.view.View.OnClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    Button userLocation;`enter code here`
    GPSTracker gps;

    PlacesTask placesTask;
    ParserTask parserTask;

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.atv_places);


        autoCompView.setThreshold(1);

        autoCompView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                placesTask = new PlacesTask();
                placesTask.execute(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        try {
            // Loading map
            initilizeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    }


    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {

        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());

        } 
        finally {

            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }

    // Fetches all places from GooglePlaces AutoComplete Web Service
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... place) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            // Obtain browser key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
            String key = "key=AIzaSyDTg7d-JNRLRxe75QDEEeAGr1xnSHGX9V4";

            String input = "";

            try {
                input = "input=" + URLEncoder.encode(place[0], "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // place type to be searched
            String types = "types=(cities)";

            // Sensor enabled
            String sensor = "sensor=false";

            // Building the parameters to the web service
            String parameters = input + "&" + types + "&" + sensor + "&" + key;

            // Output format
            String output = "json";

            // Building the url to the web service
            String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/" + output + "?" + parameters;

            try {
                // Fetching the data from we service
                data = downloadUrl(url);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }


        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // Instantiating ParserTask which parses the json data from
            // Geocoding webservice
            // in a non-ui thread
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }
    }

    // A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;

            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();


            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                // Getting the parsed data as a List
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String[] from = new String[] { "description" };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.layout.listview_layout };

            // Creating a SimpleAdapter for the AutoCompleteTextView
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), result, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from, to);

            // Setting the adapter
            autoCompView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Updated code update, everything looks fine it is just that there is nothing appearing still when I type in a place.

I have made the google maps half and half with a listview as well so if anyone has any good solutions on how to get them to work together that would be great.

Comment: What bits aren't working? Try to create an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can better help you with a specific issue rather than "this doesn't work!" and you might also find that the act of creating the MVCE helps you understand what's going wrong before you even need to ask.

Comment: I have the textview on the screen but when I enter a place nothing happens

Comment: Your code example is 351 lines long, it's too much for a random stranger to be asked to debug for you with no further help. Try cutting down the code that you've posted until you have an MVCE and you have located that the issue resides in a single method or class at least.

Comment: Im not sure where the problem resides so I was hoping to get some input on if it is set up correctly and if the code is alright.

Comment: From the code above, you did not do anything to update your listview in the `onPostExecute()` method of `ParseTask`. You might check out this tutorial for some details on implementation: http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-autocompletetextview-with-google-places-autocomplete-api/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use a library that provides a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget, check out [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (I'm the developer).  After setting it up with your API key, you could add a working Places API autocomplete to your layout with something like:

```
<net.sf.sprockets.widget.GooglePlaceAutoComplete
    xmlns:sprockets="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/place"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    sprockets:types="(cities)"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help but please can you give further instruction on how to implement this and how it works. Cheers